# ionic radio button validation

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, ionic-framework

I'm doing a form using ionic/angularjs to my application. There I've used validation to all the fields. But my validation on radio buttons do not work properly.It is showing a error message if a radio button is not chosen(Like it should) But also it shows a error message even if I've selected a radio button. How can I fix this?

OR How can I set a default checked radio button?

My form

```
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : (userForm.choice.$invalid || userForm.choice.$pristine) && submitted }">
            <label class="labelColor"><h5><b>Select Standing Order Type</b></h5></label>
            <ion-radio ng-model="choice" name="choice" id="choice" ng-value="'A'">Utility Standing Order</ion-radio>
            <ion-radio ng-model="choice" name="choice" id="choice" ng-value="'B'">Own Account Standing Order</ion-radio>
            <ion-radio ng-model="choice" name="choice" id="choice" ng-value="'C'">Third Party Fund Transfer Standing Order</ion-radio>
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="(userForm.choice.$pristine && submitted) ||( userForm.choice.$error.required && submitted)" >Standing Order Type Should Be Selected.</span>
            </div>

          <!-- BUTTONS -->
            <div class="col"style="text-align: center">

               <button align="left" class="button button-block button-reset" style="display: inline-block;width:100px;text-align:center " type="reset"
                        ng-click="submitted = false;  reset()" padding-top="true">Reset</button>
                <button class="button button-block button-positive"  style="display: inline-block;width:100px "
                    ng-click="submitted=true; "padding-top="true">Proceed</button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I would ask you to: 1 - simplify your HTML code (we don't need to know all the details, like CSS IDs or classes); 2 - show us the JavaScript; 3 - post it in a plnkr or JSFiddle

Comment: my validation part is completely done within html

Comment: Then see #1, if you might.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set default value of radio button in  in ionic framework
Follow this code:-

```
enter code here
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-content>  
        <div class="list">
            <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in clientSideList" ng-value="item.value" 
             ng-model="data.clientSide"> {{ item.text }}
            </ion-radio>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</body>

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.clientSideList = [
        { text: "Backbone", value: "bb" },
        { text: "Angular", value: "ng" },
        { text: "Ember", value: "em" },
        { text: "Knockout", value: "ko" }
    ];
    $scope.data = {
        clientSide: 'ng'
    };  
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Ionic docs state that [`ion-radio`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRadio/) works like Angular's [`input[radio]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D). You can use `ng-required="true"` like this:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="onSubmit(myForm.$valid)">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-radio ng-model="choice" name="choice" id="choice" ng-value="'A'" ng-required="true">Choice A</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="choice" name="choice" id="choice" ng-value="'A'" ng-required="true">Choice A</ion-radio>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

You can then use it in concert with an error message. I use [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages). Example:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.gender.$error"
     class="form-errors"
     ng-show="myForm.gender.$invalid && myForm.$submitted">
    <div ng-messages-include="views/form-errors.html"></div>
</div>
```